# Choose software tool for basic analysis

Tags: data-mining, large-data, software

(I am pretty novice in data analysis) So, I have a set of elements (~10<sup>5</sup>). All elements splitted for some classes of disjoint sets. Actually, there are two systems of sets.

```
ID  Category1   Category2
-------------------------
 1          A       "one" 
 2          C     "three"
 3          C       "two"
 4          B       "one"
 ...
```

I need perform some simple analysis on the data. For example, I need obtain quantity of elements for each pair of categories ($ Category1\times Category2 \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $). The following is the sample of this map.

```
Category1   Category2   Quantity
--------------------------------
        A       "one"        201
        A       "two"       1777
        A     "three"        846
 ...
        B       "one"         96
        B       "two"       8346
 ...
```

Also, I probably need to analyze relation between `Category1` and `Category2`. What kind of software tool should I use to perform such analysis?

Answer (score 3):

R is ideal for performing data manipulations and analysis:

```
> mydf
  ID Category1 Category2
1  1         A       one
2  2         C     three
3  3         C       two
4  4         B       one
> 
> with(mydf, table(Category1, Category2))
         Category2
Category1 one three two
        A   1     0   0
        B   1     0   0
        C   0     1   1
> 
> aggregate(Category1~Category2, mydf, length)
  Category2 Category1
1       one         2
2     three         1
3       two         1
>
```

Comment: I agree completely with this answer, but one should be aware that R can have a pretty steep learning curve with syntax that is not always clear at first sight. If one is going to continue doing this type of data analysis, however, the effort invested at the beginning soon becomes a most valuable investment.